# Hexagon Image with Color Overlay?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, tailwind-css

I'm trying to design a website section that has 3 hexagons lined up. Inside the hexagons I want an image, which I have figured out how to do. BUT I also want to add a color overlay. Every time I try, the image disappears and the overlay gets doubled up in some places because of how I had to make the hexagon shape.

You can check out the code or see it live: https://jsfiddle.net/dfmcu4gt/

If you could tell me how to do this in tailwind CSS that would be even better.

```css
#overlay {
  background: rgba(9, 37, 90, 0.4);
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 173.21px;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
  background-image: url(https://www.uplers.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Hiring-Web-Developers-Agencies-vs-Freelance-Portals.jpg);
  background-size: auto 346.4102px;
  background-position: center;
}


.hexagon1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 173.21px;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
  background-image: url(https://www.octalsoftware.com.sg/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/inhouse-developers-team.jpg);
  background-size: auto 346.4102px;
  background-position: center;
}

.hexagon2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 173.21px;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
  background-image: url(https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/WordPress%20developer%20reviewing%20WordPress%20core.jpg);
  background-size: auto 346.4102px;
  background-position: center;
}

.hexTop,
.hexBottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 212.13px;
  height: 212.13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background: inherit;
  left: 43.93px;
}

/*counter transform the bg image on the caps*/
.hexTop:after,
.hexBottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 300.0000px;
  height: 173.20508075688775px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-86.6025px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-86.6025px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-86.6025px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.hexTop {
  top: -106.0660px;
}

.hexTop:after {
  background-position: center top;
}

.hexBottom {
  bottom: -106.0660px;
}

.hexBottom:after {
  background-position: center bottom;
}

.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.0000px;
  left: 0;
  width: 300.0000px;
  height: 173.2051px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" class="hexagon">
  <div class="hexTop"></div>
  <div class="hexBottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="hexagon1">
  <div class="hexTop"></div>
  <div class="hexBottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="hexagon2" style="">
  <div class="hexTop"></div>
  <div class="hexBottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image disappears because the overlay override the background property, I think you should reconsider how you're building the hexagons. Or try a different approach https://jsfiddle.net/713u40tm/ I kept the overlay and hexagon holding the image separate because i don't know you'd handle image insertion, otherwise they be both on the same element https://jsfiddle.net/hfu0jk9z/